# Using child gnome-terminal for running Xvfb

Tags: python, bash, selenium, terminal

I want to run a python script which is inside a bash script. Python script uses selenium web driver so in order to use firefox as a headless browser, I need to install Xvfb first. I want to install Xvfb on another terminal like a popup for installing Xvfb and then starting Xvfb.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"sudo apt-get install Xvfb; Xvfb :99 -ac; export DISPLAY=:99; exec bash\"" 
echo -e "\n-----Welcome to automation script-----\n"
echo -n "Enter username : "
read username
```

I want Xvfb to continue running like shown in the image.

[image]

and I want to focus back on parent terminal. Or any other solution through which I can install and then start xvfb and continue with my script. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [xvfb-run](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xvfb-run.1.html) to run you command inside Xvfb environment.